# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds, Theorem 5-2(2)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the proof of Theorem 5-2 of Spivak *Calculus on Mannifolds*, are the two sets $\{f(a):(a,0)\in V_1\}$ and $\{f(a):(a,0)\in V_1'\}$ the same?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty in posting images of the proof. Next time you can either give a sketch or do the same. I don't think everyone has a copy of this book or for some, we aren't willing to torture ourselves again so providing some more details is always nice.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether my answer is right or not,if you have free time please check it. Any help will be very much appreciated !

$\textbf{1.}$

$$\{g(a,0):(a,0)\in V^{'}_1\}=\{f(a):(a,0)\in V^{'}_1\}\Rightarrow$$$$ V^{'}_{2}\cap f(W)=U\cap f(W),$$ since $$V^{'}_{2}\cap f(W)=\{g(a,0):(a,0)\in V^{'}_1\},U\cap f(W)=\{f(a):(a,0)\in V^{'}_1\}.$$

$\textbf{2.}$

$$V^{'}_{2}\cap f(W)=U\cap f(W)=V_{2}\cap f(W) \left ( V_2:= V^{'}_{2}\cap U\right ),$$
owing to 
$$A\cap C=B\cap C\Rightarrow A\cap B \cap C=A\cap C=B\cap C.$$

From above, we have $$\{f(a):(a,0)\in V^{'}_1\}=V_{2}\cap f(W)=\{g(a,0):(a,0)\in V_1\}=\{f(a):(a,0)\in V_1\}.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box$$